# Injecting IHttpContextAccessor into ApplicationDbContext ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to figure out how to get access to the current logged in username outside of an ASP.NET Controller.

For example I am trying to do this:

[Track Created and Modified fields Automatically with Entity Framework Code First](http://benjii.me/2014/03/track-created-and-modified-fields-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first/)

To setup tracking on entities in the `DbContext`.

Here is my `ApplicationDbContext` but I keep getting an error saying `_httpContextAccessor` is `null`:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    : base(options)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context there is a `AddHttpContextAccessor` extension method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try injecting the [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor) Interface

You can even abstract it further by creating a service to provide just the information you want (Which is the *current logged in username*)

```
public interface IUserResolverService {
    string GetUser();
}

public class UserResolverService : IUserResolverService {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public string GetUser() {
        var username = accessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ;
        return username ?? "unknown";
    }
}
```

You need to setup `IHttpContextAccessor` now in `Startup.ConfigureServices` in order to be able to inject it:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
//OR
//services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();
```

and pass that to your repository as needed to record associated username

Comment: I just saw a post on this actually. Should I just inject it into my ApplicationDbContext and create a private property?

Comment: More or less. yes

Comment: Alright, I am going to give it a go hoping that it is automatically injected.

Comment: And one from the same site to linked to in your post http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/

Comment: Hmm look at my updated post. I keep getting _httpContextAccessor is null

Comment: Update article says the same thing should work http://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/

Comment: Do you really think I need to install Session just so HttpContextAccessor can be injected into my controller?

Comment: No. I'm just showing that for an example as it also shows how to use `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: @BlakeRivell, Apparently it is not setup automatically. You have to add it to the services collection in order to be able to inject it.

Comment: I added it and still getting the same null error. I used services.AddScoped

Comment: hmm i don't have an IUserResolverService. Resharper or Intellisense isnt showing an reocmmendations.

Comment: No. that is a custom interface you can create yourself to abstract the direct calls to the http context accessor.

Answer (score 6):

@Nkosi has the correct answer but please note that IHttpContextAccessor is now under the namespace:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

And no longer under:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
```